# Change the color of the border in go js

Tags: javascript, colors, gojs

I would like to change the black border to green when my changeColor function is called on click

I would like to know if someone can help me to find a solution because unfortunately I am stuck on it.

I thank you in advance for your answer
[view project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8aaG.gif)

```
var commandsAdornment = $(
    "ContextMenu",
    $(
      go.Panel,
      "Auto",
      $(go.Shape, {
        fill: null,
        stroke: "deepskyblue",
        strokeWidth: 2,
        shadowVisible: false,
      }),
      $(go.Placeholder)
    ),
    $(
      go.Panel,
      "Horizontal",
      { defaultStretch: go.GraphObject.Vertical },
      $(
        "Button",
        $(go.Shape, {
          geometryString: "M0 0 M3 2 L3 0 7 0 7 10 3 10 3 8 M5 6 7 4 9 6 M10 0",
          fill: "",
          margin: 3,
        }),
        { click: changeColor },
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: What is `changeColor` ? Please add a minimal working example of your code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this as a "ContextMenuButton" **GraphObject.click** event handler:

```
    {
      click: (e, button) => {
        const node = button.part.adornedPart;
        const shape = node.findObject("SHAPE");
        if (shape) {
          e.diagram.commit(diag => shape.stroke = "green");
        }
      }
    }
```

This of course assumes that you have named the **Shape** that you want to modify with the `{ name: "SHAPE" }` property in your node template.